# How would interspecies lovers with alien body plans safely engage in physical intimacy?

Tags: internal-consistency, xenobiology, reproduction, interspecies-relations, sex

Now I had previously asked how a loving interspecies couple would work around very Alien Body Plans that is now sadly closed ([How will interspecies lovers overcome different body plans?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/193358/how-will-interspecies-lovers-overcome-different-body-plans?noredirect=1#comment599349_193358))

That question was my attempt to dip my toe in the water, to see weather or not the idea had any merit.  This is the question a lot of people thought I was asking.

Now to explore this lets bring back the example couple.

Let’s call them Ms. Smith and Mr. Xurkesh.

Now as you might have guessed they have been carrying on quite the courtship, she regales him with tales of her journey through the cosmos as an explorer, he recites romantic poetry in his native language (which sounds like an odd mixture between whale song and a broken garbage disposal) and they regularly watch the latest stream movie from Earth on the couch.  All in all, typical couple stuff.

One day after little too much to drink, they begin talking about...let’s call it the **Next Step**.  Both are intrigued, both wonder could they even go to the **Next Step**?
They decide to table it and go about their work the next day but they carve out time to seek out friends to ask for advice on the topic.

Now for Mr. Xurkesh, he is noticeably bigger and sharper, with limbs and teeth designed to rip prey apart.  Good when your eating tough armored megafauna, not so good for those tender moments.  Naturally he doesn’t want a Woman of Kleenex situation, mostly because he doesn’t want to hurt the woman that he has fallen for, even by accident.

As for Ms. Smith, her job may be to explore the galaxy, but she is not a Captain Kirk with a girl, boy, hermaphrodite, indeterminate, and undecided in every star port from here to Andromeda.  Xurkesh was her first interspecies partner and just finding a way to safely kiss him was a challenge, and not because he kept checking her over for any accidental wounds.

So naturally they both talk to their friends, some of which are also in loving interspecies couples, others may have dabbled with it in college, but the point is Smith and Xurkesh are looking for advice on how to proceed to the next step both safely and to make it something special for their better half.

So now I ask you a question on their behalf which is: **How would a loving interspecies couple with vastly different body plans safely engage in physical intimacy?**

Comment: What is still missing after the answers you got to your other question?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica an actual answer of how it can be done safely.  It is one thing to say be careful, it is quite another to actual explain how.  Besides since there are three votes to try and reopen the last question, clearly others have more to say on the subject.

Comment: Arent Klingons just humans with stuff on their faces?

Comment: @DTCooper I believe a presented artwork is a non-canon fan redesign. In any case the name is irrelevant to the question, as its not specifically about klingons.

Comment: Much better! This question is properly focused.

Comment: They wouldn't.  Just handwave reality.

Comment: Well, Mr. Xurkesh has a roughly horse like body plan; so, just Google "woman having sex with a horse" and you will find many videos to answer your question in both graphic and exact detail.

Comment: I'm, uh, going to need more diagrams... for science

Comment: First you have to think about what sex organs your aliens have, the human penis is extremely simple compared to what is available just in earth life.

Comment: They could engage in physical intimacy in probably most of the many ways in which humans would engage in physical intimacy. There would only be a few things that might not be practical. If you're looking for a list, it would be a pretty long one, and probably not appropriate for this site, both in terms of the contents of the list and because it's a list. Although you seem to be assuming he doesn't have much self-control, or is incapable of being gentle, which would be a (significant, but perhaps not insurmountable) problem between humans as much as it would be for your aliens.

Comment: This question makes me wonder what "alien kinks" would be like. What would be the "I like feet" equivalent for such an alien species? This is such a wonderful area to explore!

Comment: Why do you have a duplicate of this question active? You should have gotten the first reopened. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/193358/how-will-interspecies-lovers-overcome-different-body-plans

Comment: @NomadMaker after it was closed and after the answers I got I couldn’t edit or delete it so I simply decided to reformat it into this question.  Blame the Opinion-Based Police.

Comment: The rules state that you need to fix the question and get it reopened. Just making a new one is against the rules.

Comment: @NomadMaker The lock said “edit it or post a new one” besides that one was about weather the couples could be successful, and people focused on the physical side of things because that was the only area they thought a different body plan was relevant, so this question pivoted towards that.  Meaning it’s not really a duplicate, so much as a different angle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Well, with technology and a bit of creativity of course!**

There are several options, all depending on how transhumanist (or transalienist!) the couple is willing to go. Here's a list of potential workarounds/ways the young couple can get it on, ordered from low to high investment:

- **No touching:** there's plenty of two-partner erotic activities that people can partake in that don't involve physical contact. Maybe they can watch x-rated movies, listen to erotic audio recordings, or just watch each other as they participate in their species' brand of self-pleasure. Maybe they can play sexual games, like truth or dare with each other (eg "in lurid detail, describe one of your sexual fantasies" or "I dare you to undress in view of the window" both of which wouldn't require physical contact)
- **Drugs/restraints:** Since Xurkesh has a lot of hard edges, bulky muscles, and can easily crush his partner, one solution would be to inhibit his movement. Maybe there's a drink similar to alcohol that makes him--while not lethargic--weaker in his movement so that in the throes of passion, he doesn't accidentally crush his partner. Alternatively the couple can try bondage, restricting Mr. Xurkesh's movements so he can't hurt his partner.
- **VR Sex:** While VR sex is currently in its technological infancy, it *does* already exist. It's only reasonable to assume that this technology will be far more advanced in the future. If "full dive" VR is possible--that is fully immersive and nigh-indistinguishable from reality that works via brain-interface--the couple could just have sex in VR. There, the woman could, for example, wear a human avatar version of herself that's just as strong as her partner and also has her "equipment" modified to be compatible with her partner's avatar's sexual organs. If they want to spice it up, she could even adopt an alien avatar or he could adopt a human one--the choices are virtually limitless. Even if "full dive" VR somehow does not exist, traditional VR in a rig with appropriate animatronic sex toys could also work.
- **Human plus:** If the couple deems their relationship has reached a serious level, they might invest in themselves to become more compatible with their partners through self-alteration. For example, the woman might get gene-mods that make her muscles stronger and skin denser so it cant causally get pierced by Mr. Xurkesh's spikes and he might undergo a procedure that makes it so his saliva isn't toxic to Ms. Smith biology. Going further, maybe Ms. Smith installs synthetic pheromone glands so that she can communicate her emotions better and more naturally to her partner or Mr. Xurkesh might have auxiliary vocal chords installed so that he can speak at human frequencies.
- **Human ultimate:** Who needs pesky skin, bones, grey matter, and all those "human-y" bits anyways? Ms. Smith sure doesn't! Taking the next logical step for any space-borne adventurer who wants to live forever, she decides to become an infomorph, uploading her brain into a computer (slowly or all at once, her pick). Now, as software, she has all sorts of exciting possibilities available to her. For example, she could simply remotely pilot ("posses") a humanoid android that's tailored to look like her yet is engineered to be sexually compatible with her partner's species. Alternatively, she could inhabit a bio-printed female version of Mr. Xurkesh's species. Going even further, if her partner has a mental interface, she could live entirely digitally, projecting an avatar of herself directly into Mr. Xurkesh's vision and sending the appropriately simulated tactile signals directly to his brain when her avatar touches him.

Comment: Why is only Ms. Smith getting modifications? Surely Mr. Xurkesh could become "Human plus": dulling/removing the spikes, de-toxifying (to humans) the saliva, etc..

Comment: I don't know Xurkesh's species and anatomy well enough to make many meaningful suggestions, however in the "human plus category" 50% of my recommendations apply to Mr. Xurkesh. Naturally, Mr. Xurkesh could also upload himself or perform modifications.

Answer (score 33):

#### With clear communication and active consent.

I'm going to assume discussion and light contact (eg hugs) just works between species. It sounds like your asking more about the sexual side of intimacy than the cuddles on the couch.

This is going to vary considerably depending on the two races I could make guesses based on the picture and write some inter species smut (limb A goes into receptical B, etc) - but in the end it comes down to a discussion between the parties like so:

"I've enjoyed our time together and I'd like to do more with you"

"Me too. But I'm not really sure what to do. I'm a bit out of my depth and unsure but excited to try, so tell me what should I do"

"Ok manoeuvre this thing in this pattern. Yup like that. That feels really good. What would you like me to do to you?"

Etc...

Calm exchange between two biological machines tricking the other into releasing happy hormones. My suggestion is write it like 2 teenage humans who dont understand each others bodies but are following all the best practices of informend consent... it's basically the same story just the parts dont interlock as neatly.

Comment: Huh, very insightful.

Comment: It could be helpful too, if they have possibility to get information about the body of the other species otherwise, like read a book, watch a documentary... And if they are not open minded enough to talk to each other, they would not be open minded enough to get in close contact with other species I assume... Maybe they need to invite some "tools" because the bodies are this different in size and shape

Comment: Also there are real world couples who can't have "traditional" physical (PIV) intercourse, including same sex couples, people with medical limitations (Vaginismus, certain paraplegia,  etc) and people who just don't want to (asexuals). These people all can still have healthy, satisfying relationships while making necessary accommodations for what they personally are comfortable doing.

Comment: Always remember to consult your Harkness Test if confused about consent...

Answer (score 12):

**prosthetics AKA sex toys**

This very funny [short story](http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/kritzer_10_13/) by Naomi Kritzer narrates how a human/alien couple's special request to a sex-toy business leads to a whole line of artificial private parts -- measurements, variations, product-testing -- and their increasing popularity as we find inter-species love isn't so rare, just mostly hidden.

(Disclaimer: no, I did not search for "alien sex toys" -- I read that story several years ago. All of her stuff is that good. Actually, I did search "short story alien sex toys", but only to find that story on-line).

Comment: Thanks and by the way, no judgment there are probably a lot of people who have something in their internet history like that.  Me for example, there is a genre for Dino erotica that I learned existed by watching a Sci fi film reviewer named SFDebris when he reviewed Jurassic Park (https://sfdebris.com/videos/films/jurassicpark1.php) he showed an example of one such book whose tittle was so funny I immediately googled it to see if it was a real book.  It was.

Comment: In the computer hardware world we call these things adapters.  Much like how we have HDMI to Display Port adaptors someone would inevitably make a Human Male to Alien ??? adapter.

Comment: @Anketam I suppose Nadia from American Pie might enjoy the "Sherminator" explaining how he has an adapter for use with human females, but most people like their sex toys less clinical, and in colors, sizes, temperatures, maybe shapes that don't quite naturally occur.

Answer (score 10):

> How would a loving interspecies couple with vastly different body plans safely engage in physical intimacy?

Physical intimacy extends way past the mere act of intercourse or physical penetration. Even for the human with human couple, there are cases where one or both members of the couple has had their genitalia altered or removed out of medical concerns (think of a cancer that requires removing or altering part or the entirety of the genitalia). It doesn't mean that physical intimacy cannot happen, but just that it needs to be adapted to:

- provide gratification to the giver and the receiver
- be compatible with the physical capabilities of both the giver and the receiver

Again, as I hinted in my answer to your other question, communication between the partners is key. If A finds pleasurable to be scratched behind the hear and B can do that without being hurt or hurting, that is a valid way of expressing and living physical intimacy. There is no "one size fits all" answer for this just considering the body plan. It really depends on the individuals involved.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry if I sounded rude earlier, it’s just that I work hard on these questions, and I’m constantly hounded by the Opinion-Based police who like to close my questions within 24 hours.  And I’ll admit, I might have had a little too much fun with the story on this one.

Comment: @JacobBadger, no problem, I imagine that editing that question after all the answers received was kind of impossible.

Comment: Yeah kind of.  I also didn’t think the question through, especially the part where people would think that differing body plans would only matter in...the next step, so I decided to just refine the question here.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose as an addon to the already excellent answers present here the following:

You need to know first and foremost how members of your alien species would engage in their own equivalent of intercourse. If they function differently (think egg laying frogs, where there isn't quite any intercourse happening) then they might not have the same kind of expectations from any kind of intimate exchange.

Your description of a, to simplify, dangerous to touch male, makes me think that their females have strategies to overcome being shredded themselves. Which Ms. Smith could emulate with help from Mr. Xurkesh through communication, watching educational movies and so on, as already said in other answers.

Comment: In one book I read the man invited had to deny the invitation, his kind of sex would only work with the 7 other genders of his species, (and I think he would not qualify anymore, as space travel damages the system for them.)

Answer (score 2):

I will write about the safety, how they would come to the point to speak and find a consent about it, is another point. I think we agree, that language and sharing thoughts is not the problem in different body shapes, but touching could be.

Option 1: make Mr Xurkesh less dangerous

Depending on the dangers that Mr Xurkesh offers,for example stuff the spikes with cork, place protective shields over the sharp parts, and never let him position above the Ms.

Maybe Ms. Smith has some dangers to offer too? Maybe her saliva causes skin rash in Mr Xurkesh?

Option 2: use/invent tools to help

The arms of Ms Smith are too short to reach a part of Mr Xurkesh safe? Use a telescopic tool to reach it.

The claws of MR Xurkesh are too sharp or too big to touch parts of Ms Smith? Use some small/soft tool with a handle, that gives MR Xurkesh enough control over it.

In conclusion you need to have an image (even in your mind) how romantic physical contact would be between intra-species-couples, and then try to find solutions how the "other" species could cause the same "happy feelings".

Depending of the characters (which I assume as open minded, because they came in close contact with other species) they may need planning for the solution, or may use improvisation to overcome appearing boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe you don't need to be so gentle?**

A lot of the anserws focus on how to practice sex while avoiding harm entirely. There are pretty good answers but I feel there's a angle that hasn't been explored. Sometimes pain, and small, controlled ammounts of bodly harm can be a positive part of the sexual encounter.

Perhaps, to an extent, the pushing round, beating, piercing of the skin is acceptable and even desirable. For someone into needle play, the spikes may be a bonus! Of course, spike size may be a deal breaker in this area but then again, advanced numbing agents and the futuristic advancements in tissue repair could give you some leeway there.

Of course this needs to be done safely, o Mr. Xurkesh may neeed to practice some alien yoga to be in very good control of his movements during the act.

Something to add, you may be wondering why would your captain have those strange kinks. It sounds too convenient. Well, sure, but then again it might have played a role in the choice of the alien partner, so not as much of a coincidence there. That's not to say she only cares about him physically, but it could be what first intrigued her about him.